# ¿Puedo configurar una tarjeta Raspberry Pi desde una PC con Sistema Operativo Windows?

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi

Tengo la intención de comenzar un proyecto con una Rasberry Pi usando lenguaje Python, sin embargo tengo entendido que las Rasberry Pi solo pueden ser configuradas con Linux y en mi laptop solo poseo Windows 10.

¿Es esto un inconveniente? ¿Al ingresar al entorno de la Raspberry pi ella me otorga todo el ambiente Linux que necesito?.

Comment: La Raspberry es un ordenador de placa reducida,  lo primero que necesitarás será instalar un sistema operativo en la Raspberry (como Raspbian). Para ello si no quieres complicarte la vida usa [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/), lo descomprimes en la tarjeta de memoria de tu Raspberry desde cualquier sistema operativo y una vez insertada en ella y arrancada la Raspberry se ejecutará un asistente para instalar el SO. Hecho esto trabajas desde la propia Raspberry como si fuera un Pc normal con su SO, teclado, pantalla, desde tu pc vía SSH, etc.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla , tomare muy en cuenta tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Para poner a funcionar una Raspberry pi desde Windows solo necesitas una micro SD de 8Gb hasta 32Gb (no estoy seguro de que con 64 funcione).

- Primero debes bajar el programa para escribir la imagen en la memoria SD, esto lo encuentras en el [siguiente link](https://etcher.io/).
- Luego tienes que bajar la [imagen de Debian adaptada para la Rasberry](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) (Raspbian). Y usando Etcher preparas la tarjeta con el sistema operativo.
- Luego enciendes la Raspberry, si tienes pantalla, teclado y mouse, estás listo. Si no... se puede por ( wifi | cable ) y SSH.
- Instala phyton. (generalmente viene por defecto).
- Instala [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) o [rpi.GPIO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) (tengo entendido que rpi.gpio viene por defecto, en ese caso solo tienes que actualizar).
- Escribe tus scripts en phyton. Un ejemplo:

  ```
  import RPi.GPIO as io
  import time

  io.setmode(io.BCM)
  io.setup(17, io.OUT)

  io.output(17, io.HIGH)
  time.sleep(10)

  io.cleanup()
  ```

Hace tiempo hice un tutorial para esto, puedes echarle un ojo en [mi github](https://github.com/arie-cwhat/Tutorials/blob/master/Files/configuracion_raspberry.md)

Si necesitas saber para que es cada pin de la raspberry puedes ver [esta guia sobre GPIO](https://es.pinout.xyz/)

Comment: Gracias Arie CwHat , tomare muy en cuenta tu respuesta.